# Install 'tigerstats' package on databricks

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

Hi I can't install tigerstats package on databricks. Below is my code in R.

```
devtools::install_github("homerhanumat/tigerstats")
```

But I get the following error
[image]

My databricks runtime version is "10.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.2.0, Scala 2.12)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the dependencies of dependencies, primarily dependency on the native Linux libraries. For example, `jpeg` library depends on the `libjpeg-dev` package, and `terra` [depends on more of them](https://github.com/rspatial/terra#linux).  So you need to find all dependencies & install all of them because they aren't installed by default.  The installation method depends on if you're doing this once, or you need to have reproducible setup.

For quick and dirty approach you can use `%sh` command, but it will install package only on the driver node, so it will work only for single node clusters:

```
%sh apt-get -f install -y libjpeg-dev
```

If you have multi-node cluster, then you need to put these installation commands into a [cluster init script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/init-scripts) so they will be executed on every node.

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That error show that depended packages are not installed. That way it is working:

```
install.packages("tigerstats", dependencies=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi tried that also but it still failed.

Comment: we need to try with dependencies=TRUE will check it and update answer

Comment: it still have the same error. It says non-zero exit status.

Comment: did you put exactly as install.packages("tigerstats", dependencies=TRUE) in notebook? I tried like that on runtime 10 and it worked

Comment: Yes. It's dependencies like the jpeg, latticeExtra, mosaic, abd all have the same error non-zero exit status.